# Work Around Circular Dependencys

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

i'm trying out `sequelize` for the first time and i'm having a bit of trouble getting my database model to work.

`sequelize.sync()` fails with `Error: Circular Dependency Instruction -> Result => Instruction`

Which makes sense since my model is circular:

```js
const Instruction = db.define('instruction', {
    id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
    },
    /* more keys here */
});


//each instruction results in one or more results
const Result = db.define('result', {
    id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
    },
    /* more keys here */
});

//Relationships
//each instruction has one or more results
Instruction.hasMany(Result, { as: 'results'} );
//each result has a resulting instruction
Result.hasOne(Instruction, { as: 'nextInstruction' });
//each result belongs to a instruction which lead to the result.
Result.belongsTo(Instruction, { as: 'originInstruction' })
```

Each Instruction has 1-n results where each result has a next instruction.

Im not sure whether there is a better way to model this as a database or if i'm missing a way to makes this work with sequelize. Unfortunately i'm not that fluent in SQL so it might very well be the first.

Any Help is greatly appreciated.